# Is it possible to setup an EAV structure on PHP ActiveRecord?

Tags: entity-attribute-value, phpactiverecord

What is the best way to link tables in an EAV table structure in PHP ActiveRecord so I can retrieve the entity and all of its attributes/values?

The table structure is something like.

```
person (entity)
personAttributes (attributes)
personAttributeVarchar (attribute values)
personAttributeText (attribute values)
personAttributeInt (attribute values)
```

I found this example using a Ruby active record with EAV pattern. Can this be replicated using php active record?

https://github.com/kostyantyn/example_active_record_as_eav/tree/master/app/models

Answer (score 0):

Is that Magento I smell? I hope not. If it is, well, Magento has its own way of mapping EAV and you don't have to reinvent its square wheels. It has mechanisms in place to do what you're trying to do.

If this is something you have control over: You don't want to have separate tables by type. That is a bad idea. There should be a single EAV table per entity, with `entity`, `attribute`, and `value` columns. For 99% 
 of use-cases, `attribute` and `value` can be `string` columns (PDO returns all column values as `string`). If you want to go type-crazy (3D EAV) you can enforce `attribute` as an enum, or foreign key to an entity-specific attributes table.

For the active record class, make an associative `$attributes` array property, and during `save()` perform an atomic prune-and-apply (delete all not present in the array, insert-or-replace all values that are present). If you've chosen the (simpler) `string attribute` route, give your class `ArrayAccess` that modifies `$attributes` for added fluency. You can additionally optimize saving by keeping track of whether modifications were made with a `bool[] $attributeDiff` property.